# PowerShell - Can you pass a variable array into a Splat?

Tags: powershell

I'm new to splatting and I get an error when trying to pass a variable into splat.  Can you pass a variable into a splat and if so, how please? (Not sure if I'm using the verbiage correctly.)

**Code:**

```
$sqlInstance = @('servername1', 'servername2')
$sqlDbSpace = Get-DbaDbSpace -SqlInstance $sqlInstance | format-table
$DataTable = $sqlDbSpace
$Params = @{    
    SqlInstance = $sqlInstance
    InputObject = $DataTable 
    Table       = 'server.dbo.table'
}
Write-DbaDbTableData @Params
```

**Error:**

*Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'SqlInstance'. Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "Sqlcollaborative.Dbatools.Parameter.DbaInstanceParameter". Error: "Failed to interpret input as Instance: System.Object[]"*

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This isn't a splatting issue it's a parameter validation issue.  Remove the array subexpression `@(...)` around 'servername'. As the error indicates the cmdlet you're splatting too can't convert the array object to the expected type.

Comment: `SqlInstance = $sqlInstance[0]` (or `SqlInstance = $sqlInstance |Select -First 1`)

Comment: Thank you both.  In general, dbatools -SqlIntance can take an array, that's part of why I'm a little confused why it won't work. 

The goal of this particular splat is to use multiple instances in array.

Comment: @JM1 Which command are you splatting these arguments against?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I'm sorry, I forgot to put that part in the question.  I've updated the question to include that part of the code.

I'm wanting to get table data for an instance and write it to sql.

Comment: For future reference, `Get-Command Write-DbaDbTableData -Syntax` <-- might be helpful - it would have showed you that the type accepted by the `-SqlInstance` parameter is `DbaInstanceParameter` - no `[]` at the end, so _not an array_

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I agree the brackets don't show at the end of Get-Command DbaInstanceParameter, but they do on the dbatools site.  https://docs.dbatools.io/#Get-DbaDbSpace

Comment: That is a completely different cmdlet. You can't use the syntax for `Get-DbaDbSpace` and apply it to `Write-DbaDbTableData`. The [parameter](https://docs.dbatools.io/Write-DbaDbTableData) for `Write-DbaDbTableData` does not show the brackets.